# Pithru dosha affecting children and grand children?

Tags: pitru

Does a curse of grand mother affect children and grandchildren? if yes, what are the remedial measures? We have done every poojas , but a person raised this issue for which, I want to confirm and why does it affect?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to [Hinduism.se], Why does it affect is a different and a separate question. Please ask only one question per post. Visit [ask] and take a [tour] of our site for further understanding.

Comment: Are u asking whether curses of our ancestors affect us or not?

Answer (score 3):

If you are old and hungry, will you be satisfied if you son goes to 3 or 5 different astrologers and does pujas, maybe once every 5 years? Or will you be satisfied if they give you a little bit of food with affection once a day ?

For pitrus, their one day is a fortnight for us (shukla paksha). Their one night is another fortnight for us (krishna paksha). When their night ends (last day of Krishna paksha), it is Amavasya, and they expect some simple water and ellu (sesame) from a son in their lineage. This is called Tarpanam.

Once every 12 days (for them), it is one year (for us). So, on their tithi, they would like a bit of change in food, so instead of eating same water+sesame, they would like some rice (pinda pradhaan) and maybe few tasty snacks, and feeding brahmanas on their behalf, of course all of this should be accompanied by Vedic mantras, because those are the vibrations that carry the message that you offered food here. This is called shraddham.

Suddenly, someone might ask ? How can this food reach pitru lok ? I don't see a pipe connecting from earth.

Think of it as wire-transfer. Does the same 100 rupee note you deposit in your local bank reach the recipient living 100 miles away. No. But the bank gets the message that you deposited, so they will deposit some other 100 rupee note in the recipient's account. Similarly, if you do pinda dhaanam accompanied by Vedic mantras, these are the vibrations which inform God (bank) that food has been deposited here. Then God gives the pitrus that food, irrespective of which body they have taken due to their karma. e.g. if they are reborn as cow, then God will make sure it gets grass.

And once in a lifetime, they would like atleast one son in their lineage to do this shraddham at a special place called Gaya.

OK, these are after they've left earth.. what to do when they are with us ?? Obey them :)

These 3 duties of a son are codified in this shloka:

> Gayayam pinda dhaanam (do gaya shraddham once a lifetime)
>
> Pradhyabtham bhoori bhojanath (do yearly shraddham, and monthly
>   tharpanam -  even after having gone to Gaya once)
>
> Jeevitho vakya karnaath (obey them when they're here)

Actually, rules 1 & 2 may be easier to follow than rule 3 :)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, the question is about curse affecting descendants not about shraddham which everyone should perform.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria, why do you think they curse descendants >

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons, one of the reason could be a terrible thing done by someone on an important day maybe.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria, for A to curse B, B must have done something A does not like. Above answer gives the 3 things that Pitrus (A) expect from Sons (B). If B did not listen to A (jeevito vakya karanaath), then A would have cursed B. If B did not do shraddham on tithi (Pradhyabtham bhoori bhojanath), then A would have cursed B. Pretty much every 'terrible' thing can be boiled down to above 3.