# Are curses applicable on descendants?

Tags: curse

If a particular group of people in a family is cursed, does the curse also apply on their descendants? Example - If a family member or group of people is cursed that they will never visit a place or never perform an action on a particular day, does that also apply on descendants? Does the curse keep on applying to descendants for centuries to come?

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28543/pithru-dosha-affecting-children-and-grand-children