# What a son should do for his father's soul after 10 years of his death?

Tags: pitru

My father died 10 years ago but his soul was always with us. Recently, he contacted us and we talked. He did not wanted to tell me to do anything for him but told me that he receives whatever I do like Amavasya Offering. So kindly tell me if I can do anything else for him.

Comment: see - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28544/4435 . monthly Tarpana, yearly Shraddha & once-lifetime- Gaya pind pradhan